# MariaDB 10.3 slave fails to replicate from a MariaDB 10.2 master

Tags: replication, mariadb, mariadb-10.2, mariadb-10.3

We have a 10.2.18 master and 4 slaves with 10.2.18. Because of this bug that I've reported last week (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17420) we tried to upgrade one of the replicas to 10.3.10 to see if the bug was still there in that version.

After the upgrade, the slave began to sync binary log events from the master, but after a few seconds it stopped with the following errors:

```
mysqld[15138]: 2018-10-17  9:22:28 156 [ERROR] Slave IO thread did not receive an expected Rows-log end-of-statement for event starting at log 'main.010755' position 89390527 whose last block was seen at log 'main.010755' position 89390527. The end-of-statement should have been delivered before the current one at log 'main.010755' position 89390610
mysqld[15138]: 2018-10-17  9:22:28 156 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master, Internal MariaDB error code: 1595
```

We checked the binary log in the master and does not seem corrupted and the other 3 replicas are working ok (still with 10.2.18). Also the relay log on the slave seems ok.

The slave is stopped with the following status:

```
mainro [(none)]> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Master_Log_File: main.010755
       Read_Master_Log_Pos: 89411517
            Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.000002
             Relay_Log_Pos: 550
     Relay_Master_Log_File: main.010755
          Slave_IO_Running: No
         Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
       Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 89410432
           Relay_Log_Space: 1657
             Last_IO_Errno: 1595
             Last_IO_Error: Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master
            Last_SQL_Errno: 0
            Last_SQL_Error: 
   Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
          Slave_DDL_Groups: 16763
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 7974
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 107415
```

Does someone has experimented something similar with these combination of master and slave versions?

How can I overcome the situation?

We have already tried with RESET SLAVE, clearing relay logs and executing CHANGE MASTER TO again. But the result is the same.

I've dumped the master binary log at that position and, interestingly, slave IO thread stops in a binlog block (master binlog format is MIXED).

Downgrade is not and option because data is already upgraded.

To clarify a little more our environment:

The master/slave set that is failing is the main database server for our organization. It has 1.2 TB of data with 38 databases, views, stored procedures, triggers and complex queries.

In the same servers, we have 3 other small sets of master/slaves with the same combination (10.2.18 master and 10.3.10 slaves) and are working perfectly. Of course, these sets are smaller and simpler than the instance that is failing.

Thanks

Comment: It's not unheard of for DBMSes to change log format between versions. If you can't downgrade the up-level slave, your only other option seems to be to upgrade other servers.

Comment: @mustaccio I don't think it's a good idea upgrading the master because, if it's a bug on the 10.3.x line, I would end up with 4 broken slaves. I will edit the question with some more information

Comment: You got there by testing your upgrade in a production environment, so it's your own fault. And if it's not a bug but a feature, you're stuck.

Comment: looks like a bug to me. I'd report this too. Replication from a master one major version behind should be supported.

Comment: @danblack Thanks. I've reported the bug to MariaDB Jira. Link is: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17490